# restful redirect to path based on radio button choice

Tags: java, rest, web-services, restful-architecture, restful-url

how do I convert this method to obtain to capture the operation parameter

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String postForm(@FormParam("operacion") List<String> operacion) {
return operacion.toString();
}
```

try to create an if with the condition operation.equals ("sum") but the illegal error start of type

to later be able to compare it with the type of operation, which has been selected according to the button radio options

```
<input type="radio" name="operacion" value="suma" checked="true" />
        Suma<br>
<input type="radio" name="operacion" value="resta" />
        Resta<br>
<input type="radio" name="operacion" value="multiplicacion" />
        Multiplicacion<br>
<input type="radio" name="operacion" value="division" />
        Division<br>
<input type="radio" name="operacion" value="modulo" />
        Modulo<br>
```

when I press calculate this is the url:
http://localhost:8080/RESTFulCalculator/webresources/calculadora?num1=1&num2=2&operacion=suma,
according to the selected radio button is redirected to the restful methods?

```
 @Stateless
 @Path("/calculadora")
 public class Calculadora {

 @GET 
 @Path("/calculadora/suma")
 public String Suma(@QueryParam("num1") double num1,@QueryParam("num2") double num2)    {
 return Double.toString($Suma(num1,num2));
 }
    double $Suma(double num1,double num2) {
    double resultado;
    resultado = num1 + num2;
    return resultado;

 }

 @GET 
 @Path("/calculadora/resta")
 public String Resta(@QueryParam("num1") double num1,@QueryParam("num2") double num2)    {
 return Double.toString($Resta(num1,num2));
 }              
    double $Resta(@QueryParam("num1") double num1,@QueryParam("num2") double num2) {
    double resultado;
    resultado = num1 - num2;
    return resultado;
 }

@GET    
@Path("/calculadora/multiplicacion")
  public String Multiplicacion(@QueryParam("num1") double num1,@QueryParam("num2") double num2)    {
return Double.toString($Multiplicacion(num1,num2));
}          
   double $Multiplicacion(double num1,double num2) {
    double resultado;
    resultado = num1 * num2;
    return resultado;
 }  

 @GET 
 @Path("/calculadora/division")
 public String Division(@QueryParam("num1") double num1,@QueryParam("num2") double num2)    {
 return Double.toString($Division(num1,num2));
 }
  double $Division(double num1,double num2) {
    double resultado;
    resultado = num1 / num2;
    return resultado;
 } 

 @GET 
 @Path("/calculadora/Modulo")
 public String Modulo(@QueryParam("num1") double num1,@QueryParam("num2") double num2)    {
 return Double.toString($Modulo(num1,num2));
 }
 double $Modulo(@QueryParam("num1") double num1,@QueryParam("num2") double num2) {
    double resultado;
    resultado = num1 % num2;
    return resultado;
 }  
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use a

```
@QueryParam("operacion") String operacion
```

if you want to map the `operationc=sum` to a parameter of your method.

It looks like you want to route to different methods, pased on the value of the form input `operacion`. This is not possible. The value of the selected `operacion` will always be a `@QueryParam` or a `@FormParam`, based on the `method` of your HTML `form`. It will never be part of the URL path and it will never be available as part of the `@Path` annotation.

Comment: already implement it in a method.                                               public String Suma(@QueryParam("num1") double num1,@QueryParam("num2") double num2, @QueryParam("operacion") String operacion )    {
if(operacion.equals("suma")){    
return Double.toString($Suma(num1,num2));
}
return null;
}                                                                                                             but it does not work for me, the url is:http://localhost:8080/RESTFulCalculator/webresources/calculadora/?operacion=suma&num1=1&num2=2